# Parsing of Time Zones Inconsistencies using SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to debug some inconsistencies with the parsing of time zones with `SimpleDateFormat` here is the date format, I'm using to parse:

```
static private final SimpleDateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd, h:mmaa zzz", Locale.US);
```

Date string to parse :

> 2013-03-20, 3:36PM EDT

Parsing fails on Samsung with 2.3.5 works on HTC with 4.0.4 and HTC with 2.3.3.

Here is the output for some parsing tests:

HTC 4.0.4 :

```
Test : 2013-03-20, 3:36PM EST : Wed Mar 20 21:36:00 CET 2013 : lenient : true
Test : 2013-03-20, 3:36PM EDT : Wed Mar 20 20:36:00 CET 2013 : lenient : true
Test : 2013-03-20, 3:36PM EST : Wed Mar 20 21:36:00 CET 2013 : lenient : false
Test : 2013-03-20, 3:36PM EDT : Wed Mar 20 20:36:00 CET 2013 : lenient : false
```

HTC 2.3.3 :

```
Test : 2013-03-20, 3:36PM EST : Wed Mar 20 21:36:00 GMT+01:00 2013 : lenient : true
Test : 2013-03-20, 3:36PM EDT : Wed Mar 20 20:36:00 GMT+01:00 2013 : lenient : true
Test : 2013-03-20, 3:36PM EST : Wed Mar 20 21:36:00 GMT+01:00 2013 : lenient : false
Test : 2013-03-20, 3:36PM EDT : Wed Mar 20 20:36:00 GMT+01:00 2013 : lenient : false
```

Samsung 2.3.5 :

```
Test : 2013-03-20, 3:36PM EST : Wed Mar 20 21:36:00 GMT+01:00 2013 : lenient : true
Test : 2013-03-20, 3:36PM EST : Wed Mar 20 21:36:00 GMT+01:00 2013 : lenient : false
```

Rest of the parsings fail on the Samsung.

Can anybody explain this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know about android, but in java you can get the system properties with: `java.lang.System.getProperties()`

Comment: Which of these settings should I look for?  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties()

Comment: java.version tells you the java version... obviously

Answer (score 1):

There is no JDK available on Android at the moment.

And looking at the reference of [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) there is only one version of it. so whatever works on any android OS level should work on all levels.
The inconstancy of SimpleDateFormat is most likely due to different [locale](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html) on different devices. to fix that use one locale instead of using the device's default Locale.

```
new SimpleDateFormat(dataFormat,Locale.US);
```

Comment: I'm using the the locale parameter with `Locale.US` but parsing inconsistency is still there. Works on HTC with 4.0.4 and HTC 2.3.3 and doesn't work on Samsung 2.3.5.

Comment: could you please put the code you are using and the two outputs. I happen to have Samsung 2.3.4

Comment: I posted the date format I'm using and the String it is having trouble with. The Samsung is a Galaxy.

Comment: just tested and everything is ok, I think this might be a device specific bug.

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on, I'll report back if I find something.

Comment: I have a problem where parsing a valid date throws an exception on Android 2.3.3 but works fine on newer versions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having similar issue on a Samsung Galaxy 7 tablet.

"EDT" is not in the list returned by TimeZone.getAvailableIDs(), so a SimpleDateFormat using "z" does not work.

I'm going to make a hash table of TZ abbreviations and convert the codes to += offset.

Unbelievable, really...